# how to add button on navigation bar IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to add a button in the middle of navigation bar

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // What should I add here?
    }
```

Comment: what the issue u faced

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ur_image.png"), for: .normal)
self.navigationItem.titleView = button
```

Make sure your VC is embedded in UINavigationController :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

hope will help you. And don't forget to add target to `UIButton`.

```
    let headerView = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 25))
    headerView.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_image.png"), for: .normal)
    headerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.powerButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = headerView
```

Add button action like this:

```
func powerButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set navigation item title view to your button object

```
let powerButton =  UIButton(type: .custom)
powerButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
powerButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "power.png"), for: .normal)
powerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickOnPowerButton), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.titleView = powerButton
```

When clicking

```
func clickOnPowerButton(button: UIButton) {
   // do your stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    imageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `titleView` property of `UINavigationItem` to display a customview in the center of the navigation bar.

Custom Views can be buttons so you would need to create a `UIButton` and set it to `titleView`.

Code required for this is given in other answers, I would point you to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview). It is always better to read documentation before implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let lButton = UIButton()
        lButton.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
        lButton.frame = CGRect(x:20, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 50, height: 50)
        lButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        lButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        lButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.locationChangeAction), for: .touchUpInside)
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(lButton)
```